# How to optimize my MySQL query so that it will run faster

Tags: php, mysql, sql, curl

I'm getting 'Operation timed out after 160000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received' when an Api with the following query is called. Tables contains bulk of data, so I have put limit so that it will fetch only 2000 records per each call. But still taking large time to execute the following query.

In my PHP side, I have added `set_time_limit(0)`, increased `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` time for curl request, removed nested for and foreach but still not working.

My MySQL query code likes as shown below. Please help me to optimize the query. Thanks in advance

```
SELECT 
   SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
   tm.TXNID,
   tm.MERCHANT,
   tm.AMOUNT,
   tm.MERCHANT_TXN_DATE_TIME,
   tm.TXN_TYPE,
   CONCAT(PG_COMPANY,'-',cm.CHANNEL) AS BANK
FROM 
   tbl_master AS tm JOIN tbl_pg_rates AS c 
     ON c.merchant_channel_pg_id=tm.merchant_channel_pg_id
   INNER JOIN tbl_pg_master AS cpm 
     ON c.channel_pg_id=cpm.channel_pg_id
   INNER JOIN tbl_channel_master AS cm 
     ON cpm.CHANNELID=cm.CHANNELID 
   INNER JOIN tbl_payment_gateway_master AS pgm
     ON cpm.PGID=pgm.PGID 
WHERE 
   MERCHANT_TXN_DATE_TIME>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-09-01 00:00:00')
   AND MERCHANT_TXN_DATE_TIME<=UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-09-16 23:59:59') 
   AND txn IN('netbnk','pg','ppc','upi')
   AND tm.PROFILEID=28688 AND TXN_STATUS=1 
   AND txnid NOT IN( 
      SELECT tm.txnid 
      FROM `tbl_master` tm JOIN `tbl_irctc_refund_settled_txns` iref 
        ON tm.txnid = iref.txnid 
      WHERE 
         CANCELLATION_DATE>='2021-09-01'
         AND CANCELLATION_DATE<='2021-09-16' 
         AND txn IN('netbnk','pg','ppc','upi') 
   ) 
LIMIT 0,2000;
```

Result of EXPLAIN

```
    id  select_type  table   partitions  type    possible_keys                                                                          key             key_len  ref                                   rows  filtered  Extra        
------  -----------  ------  ----------  ------  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  --------------  -------  ----------------------------------  ------  --------  -------------
     1  PRIMARY      tm      (NULL)      ref     fk_TRANSACTION_MERCHANT_CHANNEL_PG_ID,PROFILEID,inx_txn_status,MERCHANT_TXN_DATE_TIME  inx_txn_status  4        const                                  119     12.50  Using where  
     1  PRIMARY      c       (NULL)      eq_ref  PRIMARY,fk_RATES_CHANNELPGID                                                           PRIMARY         4        dbpayment.tm.MERCHANT_CHANNEL_PG_ID       1    100.00  (NULL)       
     1  PRIMARY      cpm     (NULL)      eq_ref  PRIMARY,fk_CHANNEL_ID,fk_PG_ID                                                         PRIMARY         4        dbpayment.c.CHANNEL_PG_ID                 1    100.00  (NULL)       
     1  PRIMARY      cm      (NULL)      eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                                                PRIMARY         4        dbpayment.cpm.CHANNELID                   1    100.00  (NULL)       
     1  PRIMARY      pgm     (NULL)      eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                                                PRIMARY         4        dbpayment.cpm.PGID                        1    100.00  (NULL)       
     2  SUBQUERY     iref    (NULL)      ALL     (NULL)                                                                                 (NULL)          (NULL)   (NULL)                                  27      5.55  Using where  
     2  SUBQUERY     tm      (NULL)      eq_ref  PRIMARY,inx_txnid
```

Comment: I bet what is slow is the subquery that you have inside of your WHERE clause. `AND txnid NOT IN (SUBQUERY)` - That subquery should be totally separate from this query, because it will always return the same exact data, but in your case it has to grab all of that data for every single row that your query returns.

Comment: create an index on joining fields

Comment: Also, please adjust your query to show ALL alias.column references.  Such as Cancellation_Date.  Is that part of the tbl_master, or the refunds..  Txn LOOKS, but no guarantee from tbl_master vs refunds.  ALWAYS include when you have multiple tables involved in a query.  Helps for anyone there-after you.

Comment: What table are these in???            AND  txn IN('netbnk','pg','ppc','upi')
          AND  TXN_STATUS=1
          AND  txnid NOT IN (

Comment: and `CANCELLATION_DATE`??

Comment: Please add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <xy>` for the involved tables and please include the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ..` so we can see the datatypes and indices and how the optimizer decides to run your query.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton that is not true. When the inner subquery does not relate to the outer query, MySQL only performs it once and not for each row.

Comment: @Kaii - Well, maybe.  To perform the inner subquery only once would require creating and indexing that subquery.  MySQL's Optimizer is not necessarily smart enough.  Instead it might see `AND txnid NOT IN` and evaluate the subquery each time.  Or it might turn the `IN (SELECT...)` into `NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 ...)`.  We really need to see the `EXPLAIN` to know which optimization was or was not taken.

Comment: What version?  (This impacts the optimization discussed in the above Comments.)

Comment: @RickJames you are right, it is not guaranteed that all noncorrelated subqueries are materialized by the optimizer. It depends on a few conditions. Found the relevant documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-materialization.html

Comment: @RickJames Also you are right that `WHERE txn IN(..)` inside the suquery is not fully qualified and the optimizer might think `txn` is related to the outer query which also contains `txn`, so yeah, maybe just adding the table alias to each referenced column might already fix the problem ;-)

Comment: But we really need to see `EXPLAIN`

Comment: @Kaii - Qualifying the columns is not to fix any 'problem', it is so I can recommend indexes to help with the "optimization" you are requesting.  The Answer I wrote is predicated on the columns being in the tables indicated.

Comment: @Kaii My comment was a guess as to what was slowing down the query, I wasn't trying to say that is definitely the problem. I just didn't see anything else that stood out as to why it would take a long time for the query to run.

Comment: @DRapp yes I have adjusted all columns in the query as alias.column. but still the problem persists

Comment: @Kaii I have added the result of EXPLAIN now. Kindly check the problem description once more

Comment: See the proposed INDEX for table iref in Rick James answer. It should solve the problem.

Comment: @user11135246, as I mentioned and so too did Rick previously,  where is "txt" and "txnid" and "CANCELLATION_DATE" in your where clause. They APPEAR to be from tbl_master but not guaranteed due to the joins, and PG_Company in your Concat(), MERCHANT_TXN_DATE_TIME

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comment: **NOT IN SELECT** would kill the performance.
I would try left join with **tbl_irctc_refund_settled_txns** and put additional condition into **WHERE**. Tried in a similar situation, worked for me:

```sql
SELECT 
   SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
   tm.TXNID,
   tm.MERCHANT,
   tm.AMOUNT,
   tm.MERCHANT_TXN_DATE_TIME,
   tm.TXN_TYPE,
   CONCAT(PG_COMPANY,'-',cm.CHANNEL) AS BANK
FROM 
   tbl_master AS tm JOIN tbl_pg_rates AS c 
     ON c.merchant_channel_pg_id=tm.merchant_channel_pg_id
   INNER JOIN tbl_pg_master AS cpm 
     ON c.channel_pg_id=cpm.channel_pg_id
   INNER JOIN tbl_channel_master AS cm 
     ON cpm.CHANNELID=cm.CHANNELID 
   INNER JOIN tbl_payment_gateway_master AS pgm
     ON cpm.PGID=pgm.PGID 
   LEFT JOIN `tbl_irctc_refund_settled_txns` iref 
        ON tm.txnid = iref.txnid
WHERE 
   MERCHANT_TXN_DATE_TIME>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-09-01 00:00:00')
   AND MERCHANT_TXN_DATE_TIME<=UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-09-16 23:59:59') 
   AND txn IN('netbnk','pg','ppc','upi')
   AND tm.PROFILEID=28688 AND TXN_STATUS=1 
   AND (iref.txnid IS NULL 
   OR iref.CANCELLATION_DATE < '2021-09-01'
   OR iref.CANCELLATION_DATE > '2021-09-16')
LIMIT 0,2000;
```

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming that certain columns are in `tm`...)

```
iref:  INDEX(txnid, txn, CANCELLATION_DATE)
tm:  INDEX(PROFILEID, TXN_STATUS, txn, MERCHANT_TXN_DATE_TIME)
cpm: INDEX(channel_pg_id, PGID, CHANNELID)
cm:  INDEX(CHANNELID, CHANNEL)
c:   INDEX(merchant_channel_pg_id, channel_pg_id)
```

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Answer (score 1):

I think so many who have offered have gently skipped over one important item in the sub-select.  You are querying the ENTIRE `Tbl_master` looking for `cancellation_date` between same 2021-09-01 and 2021-09-16, and `txn`.  So if you have millions of rows, you are getting bogged down with that.  It might help with clarification and sample data, but the data query MIGHT SUGGEST that the `Merchant_txn_date_time` will ALWAYS be provided on a transaction, and the `cancellation_date` would be conditional, only when it represented a transaction against a prior one.

That being said, you would never have a cancellation prior to an originating transaction.  And your primary query is looking for transactions happening between 9/1 and 9/16, I would add that the merchant_txn_date_time is ALSO part of your subquery, but only to qualify the FROM Date.  Basically restricting I want all transactions that were on/after 9/1 that were cancellations.  Not the entire database of transaction cancellations.

Having sample data of transactions to review might help, and below is just a GUESS of what data might look like, and benefit your self in future to provide similar for clarification.

```
txnid Merchant_txn_date_time   Cancellation_Date
100   8/30
101   8/31
102   9/1
103   9/1                      9/1 Cancel of txn 100  
...
109   9/7                      9/7 Cancel of txn 102
110   9/7
...
128   9/13
...
132   9/15                     9/15 Cancel of txn 110
...
157   9/20                     9/20 Cancel of txn 128
```

The above are just examples.  Since your primary query is be the merchant_txn_date_time, it would only start at txnID 102 and stop with 132 per the date range.  But for the cancellations to be considered, it would still grab transaction cancellation id 157 even though it is beyond the 9/15 ending date as part of the inner WHERE qualifier.  As previously noted, a cancellation would always occur AFTER the original transaction happened.  Again, this is a partial guess as your cancellation date was never qualified if it was part of the `tbl_master`, or the `iref` table, hence having proper `alias.column` references through the entire query is important.

In addition, pairing that down even more.  Will the Profile ID be the same as the original transaction?  Like a person's bank account where you only want that one person's account to further restrict for same person's profile id = 28688 AND Merchant_txn_date_time >= 9/1 AND Cancellation_Date context being applied.  At a minimum, the Merchant_txn_date_time >= 9/1 will significantly help.

Finally to top-it off, I would add STRAIGHT_JOIN to tell MySql to run query in the order specifically provided here

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
        tm.TXNID,
        tm.MERCHANT,
        tm.AMOUNT,
        tm.MERCHANT_TXN_DATE_TIME,
        tm.TXN_TYPE,
        CONCAT(pgm.PG_COMPANY,'-',cm.CHANNEL) AS BANK
    FROM 
        tbl_master tm 
            JOIN tbl_pg_rates c 
                ON tm.merchant_channel_pg_id = c.merchant_channel_pg_id
                JOIN tbl_pg_master cpm
                    ON c.channel_pg_id = cpm.channel_pg_id
                    JOIN tbl_channel_master cm 
                        ON cpm.CHANNELID = cm.CHANNELID
                    JOIN tbl_payment_gateway_master pgm
                        ON cpm.PGID = pgm.PGID 
    WHERE 
            tm.PROFILEID = 28688 
        AND tm.MERCHANT_TXN_DATE_TIME >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-09-01 00:00:00')
        AND tm.MERCHANT_TXN_DATE_TIME <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-09-16 23:59:59') 
        AND tm.TXN_STATUS = 1 
        AND tm.txn IN( 'netbnk', 'pg', 'ppc', 'upi')
        AND tm.txnid NOT IN( 
                SELECT 
                        tm2.txnid 
                    FROM 
                        tbl_master tm2 
                            JOIN tbl_irctc_refund_settled_txns iref 
                                ON tm2.txnid = iref.txnid
                    WHERE 
                            -- not sure if profileId qualifies per my comment in answer
                            tm2.PROFILEID = 28688 
                            -- but would ALWAYS include the original date/time transaction
                            -- should be AFTER the primary outer qualifying dates you are looking for
                        AND tm2.MERCHANT_TXN_DATE_TIME >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-09-01 00:00:00')
                        -- wont need this >= 9/1 cancellation since above would prevent any
                        -- cancellation prior to the date in question to begin with.
                        AND tm2.CANCELLATION_DATE >= '2021-09-01'
                        AND tm2.CANCELLATION_DATE <= '2021-09-16' 
                        AND tm2.txn IN( 'netbnk', 'pg', 'ppc', 'upi') 
                            ) 
    LIMIT 
        0,2000;
```

Provided the following tables and indexes for

```
tbl_master          ( ProfileId, Merchant_txn_date_time, txn_status, txn, txnid, merchant_channel_pg_id )
tbl_pg_rates        ( merchant_channel_pg_id, channel_pg_id )
tbl_pg_master       ( channel_pg_id, CHANNELID, PGID )
-- implied/guess on columns for channel and pg_company for descriptions in query
tbl_channel_master  ( CHANNELID, CHANNEL )
tbl_payment_gateway_master ( PGID, PG_COMPANY )
tbl_irctc_refund_settled_txns ( txnid )
```